# How to detect if a Window is closed before the page hasn't been fully loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, page-lifecycle

I'm trying to find a way to detect if a Window has been closed, but the events :

[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) and [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) are only called if the page has been completely loaded.

Basically I'm trying to simulate the behavior of a modal popup window, that is, when the popup window is open, then the main page (the opener) is frozen by overlying a transparent div and when the popup is closed, in the `onunload` event, that div is hidden.

[image]

My problem is the if the content of the popup takes some time to load, and the user closes the window BEFORE it has finished loading then the `onunload` event is never fired and thus, the transparent div remains visible.

[image]

[image]

Do you know of any way I could detect if the page is being closed even if the it hasn't finished loading.

This is my code:

**In the parent (opener) window**

When the link is clicked:

```
 popUpObj = window.open(url, 'ModalPopUp', opts);
 popUpObj.focus();
 LoadModalDiv();
```

**Functions to show and hide the div**

This functions are implemented in the parent window:

```
function LoadModalDiv() {
    var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
    bcgDiv.style.display = "block";
}
function HideModalDiv() {
    var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
    bcgDiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

**In the child window (the popup)**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnClose() {
            if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {                
                window.opener.HideModalDiv();
            }
        }
        function OnLoad() {
            if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
                window.opener.LoadModalDiv();
            }
        }              
        window.onload = OnLoad;
        window.onunload = OnClose;

    </script>
```

Comment: You could add some JavaScript after the meta tags inside the head, even before the styles. Do the minimum amount of work there that you need to wire up this event (without jQuery if possible to get it to execute immediately), and don't wait for a load event. Just let it execute as it gets parsed.

Comment: Are you using an "actual" new window?  Or is this an overlay in the main window?  If it's an overlay in the main window, then you can control all the ways that the popup gets closed so you get notified that way.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just use an actual modal (Bootstrap, jQuery, roll you own, whatever). Content could be AJAX'ed in, or if you really want an external page, use an iframe. It's a bazillion times better than trying to hack window events.

Comment: Seconding @krillgar. It's good habit to put our JavaScript at the end for nearly everything, but for something like this, you want your `onbeforeunload` event handler triggered before practically anything else.

Comment: @krillgar While that would reduce the issue, it's still not a solution.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I can't use Jquery. Stupidly as it sounds I'm not allowed to use third-party libraries. This is a asp.net page with ajax toolkit and needed to use a new window so that I could easily upload files :(

Comment: @krillgar that would work if I wanted to execute code regardless of which event was raised, but in this case I only want to execute some code if the window is closed :S

Comment: hi @Axel, did you find any solution for this? :) Thank you :)